# Visual Studio 2019 is having several problems, including loading files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have been working on a project for a while now (C++), in Visual Studio 2019, but I've suddenly run into several problems that send me in circles between them.

I loaded it one morning, and found that it couldn't load any of the files.

[image: Loading File Error "Could not find file [filepath]"]

So thinking I must have accidentally moved files or something, I just copied my files again from my Github repository, but then it started having problems with every include file for the headers.

[image: Include Statement Error "Cannot open source file "Subscriber.h""]

`Manager.h` is in a different folder in the project, which makes this more confusing to me because if the source files can't open a header file in the same solution, the headers should have problems opening a different header in a different part of the project.
I've tried deleting the project settings and reloading it, but VS won't reload them, and Github desktop is freaking out with any action with the project.

Cloning my repository again and loading that just sends me back to the first problem...

Anyone have any other ideas for what I can do?

Comment: Use your OS file explorer to see if these files exist.

Comment: Welcome! Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, please [edit] your question to include all relevant info (in particular error messages) inline in the question text, not by links to pictures somewhere on the net.

Comment: Yes, those files exist, even though VS says they don't, they are where they are supposed to be.

Comment: It only let me put images in through the links...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: We understand that (as a 1 rep user) you can't embed images.  This does not prevent you from pasting the error messages in as TEXT.

Comment: @Alexandra, that means **text**, not images.

Comment: You should not use <> for includes that are files from your project. However that is not your issue.

Comment: In your code make sure that `Manger.h` does not include `Subscriber.h`

Comment: In Visual Studio it's best to copy the text of the errors from the Output Tab. And I mean output tab and not the errors list. The Output tab is in a better format and is in file order which is useful because many times 1 error can cause dozens of other errors. You fix from the top down. As a professional developer I actually set the errors list to not show up on many of the systems I use. Instead I use the output tab all the time.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your input, I will try to use all of your advice when I can finish up my other work and get back to the code

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the files are in the folder present in the error message. If they are that can be a problem with the config files of the project/solution.

Possible solutions:

1. Since you have the project in the repository, a quick way to solve it would be to delete your local project and clone the repository project. (Or clone it to a different location)
2. You can try to repace the `<Subscriber.h>` by `"Subscriber.h"`.
3. Create a new empty project and add all the project files through the **Solution explorer**:

   - right-click on the folder where you want to add the project (I recommend `Source` for the `.cpp` and `Headers` for the `.h`);
   - Select `Add` `->` `Existing item` `->` select the files.

Comment: Unfortunately none of it worked... thank you for the help though. Cloning the repository and opening it leads me back to the 'cannot open file' error, but only while in solution view, it opens fine in folder view however? Folder view doesn't let me build the project, and building in solution view prints out the inability to open all the files in the output window. And the files open fine when looking at them on my repository... Making a new project and putting the files in there still gives me problems with the include statements

Comment: @Alexandra, that's too bad, IDK if you did that, but it's not enough to put the files in the folder project, you need to add them to the project as I described, if that doesn't work it all points to errors in the souce files themselves, you need to check them.

Comment: I did it the way you described, I will keep trying to fix it, and if I can fix it, return here to post what I found. Thank you for your help!